# Disable Akamai For Magento Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, cdn, caching

We use Akamai for our CDN on our Magento store, and I'm running into some issues where it would be nice to disable the CDN for our admin area. Does anyone know a simple way to do this?

I tried creating a custom admin URL in Configuration->Advanced->Admin->Admin Base URL, but this just locked me out of my Magento admin and I had to edit the core_config_data table to get back in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the CDN have you tried allowing CORS for your files? We've run into a number of JS issues in the admin with a CDN and typically adding something like this to the .htaccess helped resolve that issue:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```